# node.js synchronous file reading operation problem?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

**Problem Statement:**

Complete function readFile to read the contents of the file sample.txt 
and return the content as plain text response.

Note:
    make sure when you read file mention its full path.
    for e.g - suppose you have to read file xyz.txt
    then instead of writing './xyz.txt' or 'xyz.txt'
    write like `${__dirname}/xyz.txt`

**My Code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let readFile = () => {

let file = path.join(__dirname,'/xyz.txt') ;
let variableFile = fs.readFileSync(file);
return variableFile.toString();
};

module.exports = {

    readFile:readFile

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an encoding parameter to readFileSync or it will return a buffer:

```
const variableFile = fs.readFileSync(file,  "utf8");
return variableFile;
```

PS: You should not use synchronous calls in production, there is a very neat API called "promisify" that allows you to use async/await or promises with fs:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

const example = async () => {
    const file = await readFile(/*...*/);
}
```